# Error: Main class FirstKaaDemo could not be found or loaded

Tags: kaa

I'm trying to run "Your first Kaa application" in Java on my local Windows 10 Machine, newest Kaa sandbox (0.10.0 running).

Everything seems to working fine, until I want to lauch the application. The compile seems to work, but if I want to Run it - it does not work.

```
[17:25:21] C:\Temp\demo_app> javac -cp kaa-*.jar *.java
[17:26:27] C:\Temp\demo_app> java -cp '.;.\*' FirstKaaDemo
Error: Main class FirstKaaDemo could not be found or loaded
[17:29:08] C:\Temp\demo_app> ls
    Directory: C:\Temp\demo_app
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       16.12.2016     17:26           1046 FirstKaaDemo$1.class
-a----       16.12.2016     17:26           1024 FirstKaaDemo$2.class
-a----       16.12.2016     17:26           1034 FirstKaaDemo$3.class
-a----       16.12.2016     17:26           1424 FirstKaaDemo$FirstKaaClientStateListener.class
-a----       16.12.2016     17:26           4368 FirstKaaDemo.class
-a----       16.12.2016     17:26           5832 FirstKaaDemo.java
-a----       16.12.2016     17:24       12063395 kaa-java-ep-sdk-HCI6YIz74KmrcJMmVhnzBTQ0F2A.jar
-a----       16.12.2016     11:50          10905 slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar
```

I followed the tutorial on the new Kaa Documentation -> https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/

Any recommendation what's wrong with the setup, causing this error?

Zipped Files: https://cp.sync.com/dl/5b41750a0#wach3qe3-gjaijp3h-wt5ub2ry-x2v4aeht

I already replaced '.;.*' with '.:./*'. It did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this command to run the demo application (from the same folder):

```
java -cp "..;..\demo_app\*" demo_app.FirstKaaDemo
```

I tried your code and it can be run this way on Windows 7.

The original command does not work for you due to the below line added:

```
package demo_app;
```